# How to insert HTML into ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

This stopped worked since angular1.2 
(text.text is HTML)

```
<div ng-repeat="text in texts" ng-bind-html-unsafe="text.text">{{text.text}}</div>
```

Any idea how to make it work back ?

Comment: you will need to include the ngSanitize module and use ng-html-bind: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-bind-html and [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service if you are using angular 1.2

```
angular.module("app").controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", "$sce", function ($scope, $sce) { 
     $scope.htmlString = $sce.trustAsHtml("<h1>HTML</h1>");
}]);

<span ng-bind-html="htmlString"></span>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cbok975a/1/)**

Comment: Sorry : I don't understand your answer: where do I put {{text.text}} ?

Comment: you have to use ng-bind-html directive. Check my demo. ng-bind-html="text.text"